# Using C++ Fstream to output numbers from text file - Need help separating lines

Tags: c++, fstream, eof

I need to create a program that takes integers from a text file, and outputs them, including the number, lowest number, largest number, average, total, N amount of numbers, etc. I can do this just fine with the code below, but I also need to process the text per line. My sample file has 7 numbers delimited with tabs per row, with a total of 8 rows, but I am to assume that I do not know how many numbers per row, rows per file, etc. there are.

Also, for what it's worth, even though I know how to use vectors and arrays, the particular class that I'm in has not gotten to them, so I'd rather not use them.

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num;
    int count = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int average = 0;
    string str = "";
    int numLines = 0;
    int lowNum = 1000000;
    int highNum = -1000000;

    ifstream fileIn;

    fileIn.open("File2.txt");

    if (!fileIn) {
        cout << "nError opening file...Closing program.n";
        fileIn.close();
    }
    else {
        while (!fileIn.eof()) {
            fileIn >> num;
            cout << num << " ";
            total += num;
            count++;

            if (num < lowNum) {
                lowNum = num;
            }

            if (num > highNum) {
                highNum = num;
            }
        }

        average = total / count;

        cout << "nnTotal is " << total << "." << endl;
        cout << "Total amount of numbers is " << count << "." << endl;
        cout << "Average is " << average << "." << endl;
        cout << "Lowest number is " << lowNum << endl;
        cout << "Highest number is " << highNum << endl;

        fileIn.close();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (!fileIn.eof())` should be `while(fileIn >> num)` since `eof` won't be set until after you've failed to read.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with the individual lines is to skip leading whitespaces before reading each value and to set the stream into fail-state when a newline is reached. When the stream is good after skipping and reading a value, clearly, there was no newline. If there was a newline, deal with whatever needs to happen at the end of a line, reset the stream (if the failure wasn't due to reaching `eof()`) and carry on. For example, the code for a loop processing integers and keeping track of the current line could like this:

```
int line(1);
while (in) {
    for (int value; in >> skip >> value; ) {
        std::cout << "line=" << line << " value=" << value << '\n';
    }
    ++line;
    if (!in.eof()) {
        in.clear();
    }
}
```

This code uses the custom manipulator `skip()` which could be implemented like this:

```
std::istream& skip(std::istream& in) {
    while (std::isspace(in.peek())) {
        if (in.get() == '\n') {
            in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }
    return in;
}
```

Comment: Hmm...Why would `peek` return different than `get`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: `peek()` doesn't return anything different than `get()`. However, if the character isn't a whitespace, I don't want to extract it and if the whitespace happens to be a newline I want to not only extract the character but also set `std::ios_base::failbit`.